# Check Android inventory/subscription outside the app itself

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

I would like to query the inventory of a user from outside the Android app, eg, on a server. Is there a token or a some sort of unique identifier that the android app can pass to the server, which can then be used to query the inventory directly from Google.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's the official API:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

Samples here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/tree/master/v2/java

To access the API we are using a "Service Account". It is a "Server-to-Server" kind of account, and it's configured using the UI at:

https://play.google.com/apps/publish/#ApiAccessPlace.